# Splitting path strings into drive, path and file name parts

Tags: python, path, split, filepath

I am new to python and coding in general.  I am trying to read from a text file which has path names on each line.  I would like to read the text file line by line and split the line strings into drive, path and file name.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import os,sys, arcpy

## Open the file with read only permit
f = open('C:/Users/visc/scratch/scratch_child/test.txt')

for line in f:
    (drive,path,file) = os.path.split(line)

    print line.strip()
    #arcpy.AddMessage (line.strip())
    print('Drive is %s Path is %s and file is %s' % (drive, path, file))
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/visc/scratch/simple.py", line 14, in <module>
    (drive,path,file) = os.path.split(line)
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I do not receive this error when I only want the path and file name.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use `os.path.splitdrive` first:

```
with open('C:/Users/visc/scratch/scratch_child/test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        drive, path = os.path.splitdrive(line)
        path, filename = os.path.split(path)
        print('Drive is %s Path is %s and file is %s' % (drive, path, filename))
```

Notes:

- the `with` statement makes sure the file is closed at the end of the block (files also get closed when the garbage collector eats them, but using `with` is generally good practice
- you don't need the brackets - os.path.splitdrive(path) returns a tuple, and this will get automatically unpacked
- `file` is the name of a class in the standard namespace and you should probably not overwrite it :)

Comment: Hi Nk, I received the following output:     Drive is  Path is "S:\Entourage\GIS\HemloBelt\Claims and file is Entourage_Claims_Master.shp", so not quite what I expected.  Each line is formatted like so:    "S:\Entourage\GIS\HemloBelt\Claims\Entourage_Claims_Master.shp",

Comment: I suppose you're on a windows machine. Before `drive, path = ...`, add `line = line.replace("\\", "/")` to replace backslashes with forward slashes and see whether that does the trick.

Comment: I found out why it was behaving as it did.  I had quote's surrounding each line string in my original text file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use os.path.splitdrive() to get the drive and then path.split() the remainder.

```
## Open the file with read only permit
f = open('C:/Users/visc/scratch/scratch_child/test.txt')

for line in f:
    (drive, path) = os.path.splitdrive(line)
    (path, file)  = os.path.split(path)

    print line.strip()
    print('Drive is %s Path is %s and file is %s' % (drive, path, file))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Hi Jordanm, this is what was printed on my screen: `code` "S:\Entourage\GIS\HemloBelt\Claims\Entourage_Claims_Master.shp",
Drive is  Path is "S:\Entourage\GIS\HemloBelt\Claims and file is Entourage_Claims_Master.shp",  Not quite what I had in mind.